# iPad Simulator does not display view from top

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I am new to iPad/iPhone development. I have created a simple view with few controls.
The controls are displayed correctly in designer. But when I run the app in simulator the view is not placed properly. The view is not laid on top to bottom. Top portion of the view hidden.
Even I tried use scroll to see if the simulator has a scroll bar but I don't the scroll bar in simulator. So there is no way I can see the controls placed on top. If I put the control leaving enough space (say center of the view) then the controls are appearing on the top of simulator.
I am not able to place the mage as I don't have the required points.

Comment: Finally I found the issue. With new release of mac they have disabled the scroll bar option to auto for getting the extra pixel as working area. I modify the setting to have the scroll bar. So now I have the scroll bar on the simulator. The other option will be command+123 which will refit the simulator.